# Recursive generation of all “words” of arbitrary length

Tags: c++, recursion, nested, permutation

I have a working function that generates all possible “words” of a **specific** length, i.e.

```
AAAAA
BAAAA
CAAAA
...
ZZZZX
ZZZZY
ZZZZZ
```

I want to generalize this function to work for **arbitrary** lengths.

In the compilable C++ code below
`iterative_generation()` is the working function and
`recursive_generation()` is the WIP replacement.

Keep in mind that the output of the two functions not only differs slightly, but is also mirrored (which doesn’t really make a difference for my implementation).

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int alfLen = 26; // alphabet length
const int strLen = 5;  // string length
char word[strLen];     // the word that we generate using either of the
                       // functions
void iterative_generation() {          // all loops in this function are
    for (int f=0; f<alfLen; f++) {     // essentially the same
        word[0] = f+'A';
        for (int g=0; g<alfLen; g++) {
            word[1] = g+'A';
            for (int h=0; h<alfLen; h++) {
                word[2] = h+'A';
                for (int i=0; i<alfLen; i++) {
                    word[3] = i+'A';
                    for (int j=0; j<alfLen; j++) {
                        word[4] = j+'A';
                        cout << word << endl;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

void recursive_generation(int a) {
    for (int i=0; i<alfLen; i++) { // the i variable should be accessible
        if (0 < a) {               // in every recursion of the function
            recursive_generation(a-1); // will run for a == 0
        }
        word[a] = i+'A';
        cout << word << endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    for (int i=0; i<strLen; i++) {
        word[i] = 'A';
    }
    // uncomment the function you want to run
    //recursive_generation(strLen-1); // this produces duplicate words
    //iterative_generation(); // this yields is the desired result
}
```

I think the problem might be that I use the same `i` variable in all the recursions. In the iterative function every `for` loop has its own variable.

What the exact consequences of this are, I can’t say, but the recursive function sometimes produces duplicate words (e.g. `ZAAAA` shows up twice in a row, and `**AAA` gets generated twice).

Can you help me change the recursive function so that its result is the same as that of the iterative function?

## EDIT

I realised I only had to print the results of the innermost function. Here’s what I changed it to:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int alfLen = 26;
const int strLen = 5;
char word[strLen];

void recursive_generation(int a) {
        for (int i=0; i<alfLen; i++) {
                word[a] = i+'A';
                if (0 < a) {
                        recursive_generation(a-1);
                }
                if (a == 0) {
                        cout << word << endl;
                }
        }
}

int main() {
        for (int i=0; i<strLen; i++) {
        word[i] = 'A';
        }
        recursive_generation(strLen-1);
}
```

Comment: The iterative function could be made with only two nested loops. One for the index and one for the letter. And please don't use "magic numbers" such as `65`, when you could use `'A'`, a character literal is just an integer with the characters encoding as the value. In fact you can loop from `'A'` to `'Z'`. (though it only works with encodings where the characters are consecutive like ASCII).

Comment: As for your problem, you should step through the code line by line in a debugger. Start with a smaller word length (like two characters) so it's easier to follow along.

Comment: Good point about the “magic numbers”. I’ll look into debuggers—thanks for the tip!

Comment: Also, how would the iterative function only require two loops? I tried it several times but I always find myself needing either more loops or infinite `if` statements.

Comment: One outer loop for the index into `word`, and an inner (nested) loop for the letter. Oh, and if you want to treat the `word` array as a string, you need to remember that all strings have one more character than reported by the `strlen` function, a special character terminating the string, the so-called "null-character" `'\0'`.

Comment: Joachim, this cannot work. Suppose the word length is 5. We need to generate 26^5 values, but your iteration only occurs 26*5 times.

Comment: @OphirGvirtzer Look again at the code in the question, that's not function to generate 26^5 values.

Comment: Ophir, just what I thought. Was just about to post this [example](http://codepad.org/J9zkKtZe) but your mathematical approach proved more useful. Notice in the output, from line 26 onward, how the column at index 0 remains at `Z`, and similarly for subsequent indices at lines 26*(index+1).

Comment: Joachim, the iterative function generates exactly 26^5 lines. Verify by redirecting the program output to a text file and running `wc -l file`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, I don't know which code you're talking about. Based on your description alone, I can't understand your intention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out you don't need recursion after all to generalize your algorithm to words of arbitrary length.

All you need to do is "count" through the possible words. Given an arbitrary word, how would you go to the next word?

Remember how counting works for natural numbers. If you want to go from 123999 to its successor 124000, you replace the trailing nines with zeros and then increment the next digit:

```
123999
     |
123990
    |
123900
   |
123000
  |
124000
```

Note how we treated a number as a string of digits from 0 to 9. We can use exactly the same idea for strings over other alphabets, for example the alphabet of characters from A to Z:

```
ABCZZZ
     |
ABCZZA
    |
ABCZAA
   |
ABCAAA
  |
ABDAAA
```

All we did was replace the trailing Zs with As and then increment the next character. Nothing magic.

I suggest you now go implement this idea yourself in C++. For comparison, here is my solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void generate_words(char first, char last, int n)
{
    std::string word(n, first);
    while (true)
    {
        std::cout << word << '\n';
        std::string::reverse_iterator it = word.rbegin();
        while (*it == last)
        {
            *it = first;
            ++it;
            if (it == word.rend()) return;
        }
        ++*it;
    }
}

int main()
{
    generate_words('A', 'Z', 5);
}
```

If you want to count from left to right instead (as your example seems to suggest), simply replace `reverse_iterator` with `iterator`, `rbegin` with `begin` and `rend` with `end`.

Comment: Truly elegant. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You recursive solution have 2 errors:

1. If you need to print in alphabetic order,'a' need to go from 0 up, not the other way around
2. You only need to print at the last level, otherwise you have duplicates

   ```
   void recursive_generation(int a) {
   for (int i=0; i<alfLen; i++) 
   { // the i variable should be accessible
       word[a] = i+'A';
       if (a<strLen-1) 
           // in every recursion of the function
           recursive_generation(a+1); // will run for a == 0
       else
           cout << word << '\n';
   }
   ```

   }

Answer (score 0):

As I am inspired from @fredoverflow 's answer, I created the following code which can do the same thing at a higher speed relatively.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <ctime>
#include <cmath>

void printAllPossibleWordsOfLength(char firstChar, char lastChar, int length) {
    char *word = new char[length];
    memset(word, firstChar, length);
    char *lastWord = new char[length];
    memset(lastWord, lastChar, length);
    int count = 0;

    std::cout << word << " -> " << lastWord << std::endl;

    while(true) {
        std::cout << word << std::endl;
        count += 1;
        if(memcmp(word, lastWord, length) == 0) {
            break;
        }
        if(word[length - 1] != lastChar) {
            word[length - 1] += 1;
        } else {
            for(int i=1; i<length; i++) {
                int index = length - i - 1;
                if(word[index] != lastChar) {
                    word[index] += 1;
                    memset(word+index+1, firstChar, length - index - 1);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    std::cout << "count: " << count << std::endl;

    delete[] word;
    delete[] lastWord;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int length;
    if(argc > 1) {
        length = std::atoi(argv[1]);
        if(length == 0) {
            std::cout << "Please enter a valid length (i.e., greater than zero)" << std::endl;
            return 1;
        }
    } else {
        std::cout << "Usage: go <length>" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    clock_t t = clock();
    printAllPossibleWordsOfLength('A', 'Z', length);
    t = clock() - t;
    std:: cout << "Duration: " << t << " clicks (" << ((float)t)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC << " seconds)" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```